# Add page in another directory to the sitemap in root

Tags: seo, google-analytics, wordpress, sitemap

So I recently added a blog section to our website. The main site is not a wordpress site.  I added the blog section by creating a new folder called blog and installing wordpress in it.  Added the appropriate link to the navbar and I'm good to go. mysite.com/blog is up and running.

I want to be sure that the entire site is benefiting from the content in the blog section, so I generated a new sitemap, but it is not picking up anything from the blog folder. The sitemap looks exactly the same as it did before I made the blog.  Can I manually add the blog page?

How do I go about tying together the root directory with the the blog directory?  I'm also wondering about this for use with Google Analytics.  For example, there used to be a shop.mysite.com. However it was a completely different root folder... so once someone navigated to the shop they were lost to GA.  I'm hoping to have everything as consolidated and buttoned up as possible so that we're not repeating mistakes.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can manually add links to the sitemap; you could write the entire document manually if you wanted to.

However, I would recommend looking into how you created the sitemap as it's not normal that it doesn't pick up the blog folder; if it's a blog with frequent updates, it's very convenient to have a sitemap that updates automatically.

Finally for Google Analytics, you simply have to add the GA tracking code to every page that you want to track; the folder where the files are located does not matter.

Comment: Thank you for the help.  I've added the GA tracking code to the appropriate php file.  I will look in to getting the site map sorted out as well.  It's definitely possible something is out of place in a big way.  Thanks again.